# NodeJS Accessing an object in the parent class constructor from the Child Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What I'm attempting is to create a Controller Class that will initialize all my routes for me with ExpressJS here's a basic example of what I have

```
class Test extends Controller {
  constructor(App) {
    const Routes = [
      {
        url: '/hello',
        execute: this.world
      }
    ];
    super({ Routes });
  };

  world(req, res) {
    return res.json({success: true, msg: "Hello World."});
  }
}
```

Controller Class

```
class Controller {
  constructor({ Routes }) {
    // I want to be able to access the items from the Routes Object here so I can loop over them and initialize them
  }
}
```

I need a way to pass this routes Object into the Controller class, It needs to have the URL so that if a route has params such as `/hello/:id` then that would be defined there and it needs to know which function to execute in the Test class.

The issue is Your not allowed to access the `this` parameter before the super has been called and you can't access it within the super either. Is there any way that I can get this object through?

Is this possible or am I missing something really obvious

Answer (score 0):

Define your routes as a `static const routes` and pass the child class in the constructor as

`super(Test)`

From the parent, you can access in the constructor

`constructor(Test) { 
    this.routes = Test.routes
    }`

This should solve the problem.

Comment: `static Routes = [{url: '/test/:id', execute: this.test}];`

Gives the error that the = is an unexpected Token

Comment: @Dectom we're you able to fix it?

Comment: @freakomonk no I wasn't I was declaring it in the class and it was giving the error